# the mysql root account becomes ''@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, account, privilege

I think the root account has lost all privileges,or this root account has been replaced by ''@'localhost'
I use windows 7.
I login in the mysql with root account

```
C:\Users\Administrator>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ******
```

when type `use mysql`,i got this

```
mysql> use mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

then i type `show databases;`,there are only two

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

This is the `net user`

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net user

\\my-201501121940 的用户帐户

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            Guest
命令成功完成。

C:\Users\Administrator>mysql -u root -p admin
Enter password: ******
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'admin'
```

I can't use root account to do anything, so I want to restore root privileges, can someone help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a little? Which account are you logged into when you access your cmd? Also, please give the output of the command `net user`?

Comment: hi @kakashihatake2,i already elaborate it.

Comment: You did not answer my second question, which account are you logged into when you access cmd? Administrator? Guest? or the Chinese/Japanese one? Can you try this command and tell me if it works? `mysql -u root -p admin`